# Trouble with data type conversions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-conversion

[https://github.com/rgrantham82/Hate_Crimes_Analysis/blob/master/Data%20Wrangling%20(1).ipynb]

if the above link doesn't work use [https://github.com/rgrantham82/Hate_Crimes_Analysis] and click on the Data Wrangling Jupyter notebook.

I am currently analyzing hate crimes data for Austin, TX. So far, I'm in the cleaning phase of it & I am having a brain-fart on how best to proceed.

So far, I concatenated 4 datasets from data.austintexas.gov -- reported hate crimes from 2017 to the present. The resulting set produced several new columns because the original columns of data, especially the 'date...', 'victim...', and 'offender...' columns were all formatted differently by the creator(s)/curator(s)...great work whomever you are working for austintexas.gov....anyways, my goal now is to:

1. The most important column for my purposes is the 'bias' column. How would I convert the data to a numerical type? I cannot visualize it with Matplotlib bc obviously it's not numerical.
2. Somehow convert the 'incident_number' data to datetime. or some other numerical data type to make visualization better.

Unless it's possible to clean and merge the various 'date' columns up & convert them, but the simplest way seems to be with manipulating the 'incident_number' column.

Btw, I'm very much a novice with Python. Any help is greatly appreciated but I'm aslo very open to advice, etc. Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 0):

1) I believe you could convert the bias column to an int.

Lets say you have a dataframe named df with the column bias.

you could do:

`df['bias'] = df['bias'].astype(int)`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html

2) For incident number you could do:

`df['incident_number'] = pd.to_datetime(df['incident_number'])`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `bias` column is text and you want numerals, for that use `Categorical`;

```
df['numerical_bias'] = pd.Categorical(df.bias)
```

2. For date-time formatting problems, use the `format` argument of the `to_datetime` function;

```
df['incident_number'] = pd.to_datetime(df['incident_number'], format='%d%m%Y')
```

The formatting documentation is available here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

3. Renaming columns in `pandas`;

```
df2.columns = df1.columns

# or if the columns don't match 
df2.columns = ['all', 'the', 'columns', 'you', 'require']

# if you want to rename only one column
i = 4
df2.columns[i] = 'new_name'
```